# Using a function with "awk" produces the "fatal: cannot open file" error

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I'm trying to
1) Look up a counter value at the top of a text file (3)
2) Read a German word in THAT line (Kellnerin)
3) Insert a new line with the incremented value in Line 2 (4)
4) Delete the original Line 1 (3)
5) Finally launch a web site with the word in its URI on Firefox

German_words.txt:

```
3
Ufer
Küste
Kellnerin
Bestellung
Gemütlichkeit
```

bash script:

```sh
GERMAN_FILE="/home/to/Desktop/German_words.txt"

echo $GERMAN_FILE

getword() {
    WORD_NUM=$(awk 'FNR == 1' "$1")

    if [[ $WORD_NUM == '' ]] ; then
        #Reach end of file
        WORD_NUM=1
    fi

    #Insert the incremented number below Line 1, i.e., Line 2
    sed -i '1i((WORD_NUM++))' "$1"

    #Delete the previous entry in Line 1
    sed -i '1d' "$1"                

    echo $(awk 'FNR == $WORD_NUM {print; exit}')
}

getword $GERMAN_FILE
/usr/bin/firefox "https://dict.tu-chemnitz.de/dings.cgi?service=deen&opterrors=0&optpro=0&query=${getword}&iservice="
```

I am getting the following errors when I test it on an online bash editor, namely https://www.tutorialspoint.com/execute_bash_online.php:

```sh
    $bash -f main.sh
    /home/to/Desktop/German_words.txt

    awk: fatal: cannot open file `/home/to/Desktop/German_words.txt' for reading (No such file or directory)
    sed: can't read /home/to/Desktop/German_words.txt: No such file or directory
    sed: can't read /home/to/Desktop/German_words.txt: No such file or directory
    main.sh: line 24: /usr/bin/firefox: No such file or directory
```

My questions:
1) Could someone please explain why I am getting the "cannot open file" error?
2) Overall, I am dead sure of a much more elegant solution. I cannot get  "sed" substitution command i.e., `sed 's/.../.../' file` working...

Comment: At a guess - `/home/to/Desktop/German_words.txt` doesn't exist or isn't readable. What does `ls -l '/home/to/Desktop/German_words.txt'` tell you?

Comment: Hi Ed. The output of your request is `-rw-r--r-- 1 to to 2327 Jul 22 06:28 /home/to/Desktop/German_words.txt` on my laptop. Thanks.

Comment: Perhaps it is something with how https://www.tutorialspoint.com/execute_bash_online.php works: Perhaps your code is run in a different environment (docker) and the `/home/to/Desktop/German_words.txt` is not found there. It will not look at a file on your laptop. Run the `ls -l "$GERMAN_FILE"` in the script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why you would think that an online `bash` editor/executor would either:

- have the files (that you're trying to open or execute) on their site; or
- have access to those files on your own system.

Unless you can arrange one of those, you'll have to test your scripts locally where the files *are* available.

Oh and, by the way, I can't see this working very well:

```
echo $(awk 'FNR == $WORD_NUM {print; exit}')
```

Since it has no input file specified, it will wait forever for user input.

---

As for a more "elegant" solution, it looks like you have a file with a current word indicator and one word per line, such as (apologies, my German is rather limited):

```
1
Ja
Nein
Bitte
Danke
```

The following function (along with full test harness) shows how you can do this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

getword() {
    # Get the current word.

    awk <gw.in '
        FNR == 1       { wordNum = $0 + 1 }
        FNR == wordNum { print }'

    # Update the current word pointer:
    #   - get point where it wraps;
    #   - create new file with new pointer, taking wrap into account;
    #   - move new file into old.

    wrapAt=$(wc -l <gw.in)
    awk -vwrapNum=${wrapAt} <gw.in >gw.in.next '
        FNR == 1 {
            wordNum = $0
            nextNum = wordNum + 1
            if (nextNum == wrapNum) {
                nextNum = 1
            }
            $0 = nextNum
        }
        { print }'
    [[ $? -eq 0 ]] && mv gw.in.next gw.in
}

# Test harness.

printf "1\nJa\nNein\nBitte\nDanke\n" >gw.in

echo "=== Before, file is: $(echo $(cat gw.in))"
for ((i = 1; i < 10; ++i)) ; do
    word="$(getword)"
    echo "=== After word # $i: ${word}, file is: $(echo $(cat gw.in))"
done
```

Running that test harness, we can see that the words come in correctly and that the file is updated as needed:

```
=== Before, file is: 1 Ja Nein Bitte Danke
=== After word # 1: Ja, file is: 2 Ja Nein Bitte Danke
=== After word # 2: Nein, file is: 3 Ja Nein Bitte Danke
=== After word # 3: Bitte, file is: 4 Ja Nein Bitte Danke
=== After word # 4: Danke, file is: 1 Ja Nein Bitte Danke
=== After word # 5: Ja, file is: 2 Ja Nein Bitte Danke
=== After word # 6: Nein, file is: 3 Ja Nein Bitte Danke
=== After word # 7: Bitte, file is: 4 Ja Nein Bitte Danke
=== After word # 8: Danke, file is: 1 Ja Nein Bitte Danke
=== After word # 9: Ja, file is: 2 Ja Nein Bitte Danke
```

Comment: Sorry about that. When I run my script on my laptop with change from `echo $(awk 'FNR == $WORD_NUM {print; exit}')` to `echo $(awk 'FNR == $WORD_NUM' "$1")` an error reads "Failed to execute child process "xterm" (No such file or directory)

Comment: @Julia, that's a very weird one. I'd start by looking in your `.bashrc` to see if there's anything in there that tries to kick up an `xterm` under certain circumstances. Other than that (a subshell running bashrc), I can't think of anything off the top of my head that would cause it: `echo $(awk 'FNR==3' inputFile)` works fine. In any case, I'd suggest using the function I posted in the latest update.